# Checking condition before inserting data to a table in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, orm, entity-relationship

I have 5 tables `User`(i.e Employee), `Positions` and `Emp_position`(which is a relationship table between the Employee and Positions). I have a department table which contains the list of all departments in my company and a relationship table `Works_in` which maps `User`(Employee) to a department. Now in the Works_in table when I am mapping `User`(Employee) to a `Department` I want to check whether the data that I am inserting in Works_in(relationship) table. That is mapping an employee to a department already has a manager mapped to it or not.

Example :

**Employee**

```
Himanshu
Bassi
BB
```

**Position**

```
Developer
Manager
Tester
```

**Emp_position**(relationship table)

```
Employee    Position
Himanshu    Developer
Bassi       Manager
BB          Manager
```

**Department**

```
Web UI
Data Analysis
Machine Learning
```

**Works_in**(relationship table)

```
Employee    Department
Himanshu    Web UI
Bassi       Web UI
BB          Web UI    # this is wrong, which needs to be checked
```

Each Employee will be mapped to a Department, But a department should not have multiple manager. Over here since Bassi and BB are manager we don't want them to be mapped to same department. So for that purpose I want to check before the data `BB    Web UI` was being inserted to our Works_in table whether the department that is going to be mapped to a department already has a manager mapped to it. So I want to include a check before inserting data to my Works_in table.

Here is my **models.py** file.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Position(models.Model):
    position_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.position_name


class Emp_position(models.Model):
    emp_uname = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='emp_name', to_field='username', on_delete=models.CASCADE, unique=True)
    position_name = models.ForeignKey(Position, related_name='position', to_field='position_name', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.emp_uname) + " " + str(self.position_name)


class Department(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Works_in(models.Model):
    emp_name = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='works_emp_name', to_field='username', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    dept_name = models.ForeignKey(Department, blank=False, null=False, to_field='name',related_name='works_on_dept', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.emp_name) + " " + str(self.dept_name)
```

Comment: Are you referring to pre_save signal? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/signals/#pre-save

Comment: documentation does not tell much about how can I override pre)save method. Can you please help me out with this

Comment: Check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching and doing some research related to my needs as mentioned in the question. We can override clean method inside the model for this and raise an error inside the clean method in case if the data entered does not satisfy our logic

```
def clean(self):
    # statements
    if condition:
         raise ValidationError('Error message')
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/signals/#connecting-to-signals-sent-by-specific-senders), you can use the receiver decorator to connect to a signal like so,

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from myapp.models import Works_in


@receiver(pre_save, sender=Works_in)
def my_handler(sender, **kwargs):
    # Your pre_save logic here

    if i_dont_want_to_save:
       raise Exception('Dont save me!')
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: But how do I resist saving, when the condition is met i.e throw validation error to the form

Comment: Validation error and Exception are raising form submit error. I wanted the form error which comes below the forms that the data is invalid

Comment: You didnt mention you have any form in the question above. This will raise an exception on application level. If you have a form, just add the check in your form clean method https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other

Comment: No thats actually django admin form, I am adding data from django admin page. Please see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58464033/raise-form-error-below-the-input-field-in-case-any-invalid-data-is-entered-in-dj/58464152#58464152

Comment: Well then you need to add a unique together rule to your model in order to get this working. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#unique-together

Comment: No unique together won't work, What I actually want to do is based on some logic of checks which generates an output. And raise data invalid error in my form itself

Comment: Your form or django admin from?

Comment: django admin form. Please refer to the second question that I have asked