# Raise Form error below the input field in case any invalid data is entered in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I am using pre_save to raise error if while entering the data any condition is not met. But when I am using `raise ValidationError()`. Its showing me error in the next page like this.
[image]

But what I actually want is the error just below my field that the data is invalid. For example the one that you get for a unique field eg username in the django admin.

[image]

The error should show in this page itself showing invalid data. How can I do this.
This is what I have tried.

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Works_in)
def check_dept_has_manager(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    print(instance.emp_name, instance.dept_name)

    if str(instance.emp_name) == "BB":
        raise ValidationError("Manager already assigned to this department")
```

Something like this.... In the red colored text.
[image]

Comment: raise in `save` method it will work

Comment: No its not working!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use clean method for this.

```
def clean(self):
    if str(self.emp_name) == "BB":
        raise ValidationError('Manager already assigned to this department')
```

This method is called before saving the object. The clean() method on a Field subclass is responsible for running to_python(), validate(), and run_validators() in the correct order and propagating their errors.

Answer (score 1):

You can respective validation in modelField as a function reference in argument  `validators`

```
def check_dept_has_manager(value):
     if value == "BB":
        raise ValidationError("Manager already assigned to this department")
     else:
        return value
```

In your model

```
class Works_in(models.Model):
      emp_name = models.CharField(max_length=2,validators=[check_dept_has_manager])
```

If you hit `save` it will show validation on field